# Sort 2dim array by column value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

I have a data structure that looks like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => something
        [1] => 1296986500
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => something else
        [1] => 1296600100
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => another thing
        [1] => 1296831265
    )
)
```

I'm trying to sort the array based off of the integer which is a unix timestamp. The following function looks right to me but is not sorting the way I want.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a[1] == $b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[1] < $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

**NOTE**
 when calling this function within a class the OO syntax is the following

```
uasort($_data, array($this, 'cmp'));
```

Comment: How is it not sorting the way you want?

Comment: What do you mean, not sorting the way you want?

Comment: Brian, if you're going to ask people to help you, at least put yourself in their shoes for 2 seconds and think about whether you actually told them what you want help with or not...

Comment: @Dan, Sorry I mean't to sort the array by integer in decreasing order

Comment: What you needed to say was "this code does sort the array by timestamp in ascending order, but I want to sort the array by timestamp in descending order". Instead you leave it where nobody can tell if your sort function works (there could be hidden bugs in code you didn't share), why you say it isn't the way you want, and what it is that you do want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sorts your timestamps in ascending order; for descending order, flip the second comparison (i.e. change `$a[1] < $b[1]` to `$a[1] > $b[1]`):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a[1] == $b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[1] > $b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Or just `return $b[1] - $a[1];` (or vice versa... whatever).

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yep, was just trying to match his existing code, along with trying to read his mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup time stamp as pivot. And use array_multisort().

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $time[$key]  = $row[1]; //unix timestamp 
}


array_multisort( $time, SORT_ASC, $data);
?>
```